# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:Ownerdetails of: me.pojo.Vehiclemaster

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working with Hibernate 4.3.1 and i got exception like 
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:Ownerdetails of: me.pojo.Vehiclemaster

these are my pojo classes..

```
Ownerdetails.java
public class Ownerdetails  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer ownerid;
 private String oname;
 private String panno;
 private String mobile;
 private String address;
 private String pincode;
 private String city;
 private String state;
 private String country;
 private String accno;
 private String bankname;
 private String branch;
 private String ifccode;
 private Set vehiclemasters = new HashSet(0);

 Vehiclemaster.java
 public class Vehiclemaster  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer vid;
 private Ownerdetails ownerdetails;
 private String vno;
 private String vname;
 private String driverlicense;
 private String unladenWeight;
 private String drivername;
 private String vtype;
 private String inscompname;
 private String instype;
 private String insfrom;
 private String insto;
 private String fitnessdatefrom;
 private String fitnessdateto;
```

and these are my Hibernate.hbm files

```
Ownerdetails.hbm.xml     
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="me.pojo.Ownerdetails" table="ownerdetails" catalog="courier" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="ownerid" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="ownerid" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="oname" type="string">
        <column name="oname" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
     .
     .
    <set name="vehiclemasters" table="vehiclemaster" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="ownerid" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="me.pojo.Vehiclemaster" />
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>



  Vehiclemaster.hbm.xml
  <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="me.pojo.Vehiclemaster" table="vehiclemaster" catalog="courier" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="vid" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="vid" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="ownerdetails" class="me.pojo.Ownerdetails" fetch="select">
        <column name="ownerid" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
      .
      .
      .
```

my jsp file
      Vehicledetails.jsp

```
  List<Object[]> l = transaction.s.createQuery
("select v.vid,o.oname,v.vname,v.driverlicense,v.drivername,v.vtype from Vehiclemaster v join v.Ownerdetails o").list();

  for (Object[] v : l) {
  <tr>

                <td><%= v[1] %></td>
                <td><%= v[2] %></td>
                <td><%= v[3] %></td>
                <td><%= v[4] %></td>
                <td><%= v[5] %></td>
                <td><%= v[6] %></td>    
  </tr>

 what is going wrong?
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to initialize `vehiclemasters` in `Ownerdetails.java` class

just declare only.

```
private Set vehiclemasters;
```

here your hibernate mapping class.

```
<class name="Ownerdetails" table="OwnerdetailsTable">
      <set name="vehiclemasters" cascade="all">
         <key column="ownerid"/>
         <one-to-many class="me.pojo.Vehiclemaster"/>
      </set>
</class>
```

Hope it will help you...

Comment: I edited as you mention above but still getting same error.like

Comment: could not resolve property: Ownerdetails of: me.pojo.Vehiclemaster [select v.vid,o.oname,v.vname,v.driverlicense,v.drivername,v.vtype from me.pojo.Vehiclemaster v join v.Ownerdetails o]

Comment: and one more think..i did not initialize anything like..private Set vehiclemasters = new HashSet(0);
...... it automatically came. actually i made relationship using phpmyadmin and create hibernate.reveng.xml file and drag my database into hibernate.reveng.xml afterwards i create hibernate mapping files and pojos from database.

Comment: "select v.vid,o.oname,v.vno,v.vname,v.driverlicense,v.drivername,v.vtype from Vehiclemaster v inner join v.ownerdetails o"

Comment: Here v.ownerdetails o and we have to link with class type reference variable not with class..  Here 'o' is in small letter. and i was linking with Ownerdetails......see here 'private Ownerdetails ownerdetails;'... it was small mistake.I hope this will help for others....